# CSV to SQL Upload

Tags: sql

I've created a 'artist' table in my database with the columns 'artistid' and 'artisttitle'. I also uploaded a csv that have the same names for headers. I'm using the below code to upload the csv data into the sql table but receive the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UndefinedColumn                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-80bd8826bb17> in <module>
     10 with connection, connection.cursor() as cursor:
     11     for row in album.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
---> 12         cursor.execute(INSERT_SQL,row)
     13 
     14 mediatype = mediatype.where(pd.notnull(mediatype), None)

UndefinedColumn: column "albumid" of relation "album" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO zp2gz.album  (albumid, albumtitle) VALUES (1,'Fo...
                                  ^
```

EDIT---------------------------------

I meant to say albumid and albumtitle! My apologies

Comment: Does the column `albumid` exist?  Also, you should tag your question with the particular flavor of sql you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a typo -- you need to use `albmid` instead of `albumid` -- maybe fix your `models.py` and re-migrate.